# AngularJS directive template with repeater

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have directive with this template that includes a repeater:

```
template:   '<div class="btn-group">' +
                    '<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn" ng-repeat="option in options" ng-click="select($event, scope)" value="{{option.value}}">{{option.label}}</a>' +
                '</div>'
```

Inside my link function, the following returns an empty array unless I put it inside a $timeout:

```
var tmp = element.find('.btn');
```

Link to fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dkrotts/XF3RY/1/

Shouldn't these elements be available at link time? If not, is there a cleaner way to handle this situation?

Comment: element.ready(function(){})

Comment: This didn't work for me. Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dkrotts/XF3RY/2/

Comment: What do you intend on doing with the `.btn` when you get it?

Comment: The radio btns can have an initial value. I need to select the appropriate value on load

Comment: I was able to accomplish this in a more "Angular" way. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/dkrotts/BtrZH/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the ng-repeat happens later, after your link function is run: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13771751/215945

You may want to try using two directives, similar to the `tabs` and `pane` directives on the Angular home page example.  The `radio-buttons` directive could define a method (using `this`) on its controller that the `radio-button` directive could call when clicked.

For details on how the tabs and pane directives communicate, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/14168699/215945